# Correct term for 'LiveCD'?

Tags: discussion

Which way of referring to Ubuntu bootable media (i.e. written from the `.iso` to a device) is best?

- Live CD

  - The traditional (generally used), but users have asked whether a 'CD' is required.
- Live USB

  - Newer (more modern and realistic), but also has a similar issue to above (asking if they can instead use a CD)
- Live system

  - Should be fairly straightforward (referring to any 'Live' media), but is not as well known (or used)
- Ubuntu bootable media

  - Should have next to no confusion in meaning, but newer users may not understand what it means
  - It's called a "bootable USB stick" in the [official install instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- Live Environment

  - Probably a better version of 'Live system'

Generally speaking, every case which includes a specific type of media (USB, CD, DVD), is going to have users querying about whether you can use a different media.

---

Tags exist for 'live-usb', 'live-cd', 'livedvd' and 'live-environment'.

Comment: I usually call them 'Live Media'.

Comment: I normally use "Installation media" for any kind of... installation media :P

Comment: I usually just say "LiveCD" myself..