# Migration of tags (live-cd, livedvd)

Tags: discussion, tags

This has already been mentioned here:

- ['livedvd' should be a synonym for 'live-cd'](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7473/266923)
- [Correct term for 'LiveCD'?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7471/correct-term-for-livecd)

There hasn't been a change yet it seems.

Do we really need [live-cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-cd), [live-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-usb), [livedvd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/livedvd), and [live-environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-environment)?

It seems that is a bit of overkill.

I can understand there is some sort of separation, because of what media the live environment is on, but these could really all be migrated together into one tag. For instance [live-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-boot), [live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live) or into an existing one.

Comment: `live-media` probably makes more sense than live-boot.

Comment: I planned sometime ago merge them all into live-environent, which is ultimately what all of them are. Your suggestions are quite poor: *live* of what? live-boot falls short since they don't only boot, they can be modified, recreated, etc.

Comment: @Braiam I was just going off the top of my head, and was trying to bring attention to the issue again. Seth's idea for tag name is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

Merge them all into [live-environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-environment), the tag wiki/excerpt is already written with the correct information about its propose:

> Its a kind of boot which directly loads the OS without actually installing it. Its good for trying out and demonstration purposes and for kiosks.

Comment: Their questions aren't necessarily about the environment though..

Comment: @Seth is not two words with their meanings carried, is just one term with its own meaning. Live environment is a term that encompass all forms of non-installed media that can be booted and used in any supported system.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the questions are about the media itself (at least moreso than the environment), which is why I think live-media is a better idea.. Just me though :)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Seth to create a tag [live-media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-media). I think the distinction between a Live USB and a Live CD or DVD is sometimes important...

Also I disagree with Braiam to merge them into [live-environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-environment). For me, the Live environment is the system booted from a live medium.

My suggestion is to have the following tags:

- [live-disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-disk) for problems with creating or booting Ubuntu from a DVD or CD

  - Synonyms: [live-cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-cd),[livedvd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/livedvd), ...
- [live-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-usb) for live bootsticks and problems with creating or booting a USB stick.

  - Synonyms: [bootstick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bootstick), ...
- [live-environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-environment) for problems related to the live system itself.

  - Synonyms: [live-system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-system), ...

I don't know what you think, but for me this is the most logical approach I can currently think of.

Comment: I would think if there was a separation between what the media is loaded on (ex.cd, dvd, usb, hdd, etc.) if there was a problem with the loading of the disk it could go to your live-disk tag, but if there is a problem relating to the disk it can always go into DVD,CD, or USB. Basically the media on which there is a problem does not seem to warrant extra tags. I honestly cannot see this (personally) as a reason to have all these tags, as there could even be live-fdd (if someone really wanted), or live-bluray, etc. it seems integration into less tags would be helpful, even if not as precise.

Comment: You make a good distinction. Live media is too much about the media while live environment is too much about the environment.. Maybe we should have both tags? I'm not really convinced a tag for both CD/DVDs and USB sticks is needed..