# Tiny tweak to the [livedvd] tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

This isn't even worth bringing up in Meta, but if I don't point it out it's going to nag at me in the back of my mind.

Observe the following set of tags:

[live-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-usb)
[live-cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-cd)
[livedvd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/livedvd)

If some helpful moderator could change the last tag to add a hyphen (`live-dvd`), it would save some poor perfectionist needless strain.

Comment: Although a different issue, it's worth giving this related issue some attention, while we are discussing the tags in question anyway: [_Migration of tags (live-cd, livedvd)_](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11878/migration-of-tags-live-cd-livedvd)

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't allowed to "tweak" tags without creating a new one and synonymizing, but we're also not allowed to create tags that only differ by a hyphen so..

Comment: @Seth Aw, that's too bad. Go ahead and add the comment as an answer and I'll accept it (just for completion's sake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we aren't allowed to "tweak" tags without creating a new one and synonymizing, but we're also not allowed to create tags that only differ by a hyphen so [Migration of tags (live-cd, livedvd)](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11878/migration-of-tags-live-cd-livedvd) is your only hope ;)